# how to retrieve values in a tab without its subtabs

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath

I'm working with python and xpath

I write a code that read a html code and I want to store some part of it.
a piece of html code is:

```
<div id="vulnerability">
<span class="title">Mozilla Firefox/Thunderbird/SeaMonkey MFSA 2013-63 through -75   Multiple Vulnerabilities</span><br/><br/>  <b>Solution:</b><br/>
Updates are available. Please see the references or vendor advisory for more    information.<br/><br/>
```

and I want just store the string in div tab and not span or b tabs.
when I write this:

```
path="//div[@id='vulnerability']"
value=xpath.search(html,path)[0].strip()
```

it stores all div tab with subtabs like span and b tabs
how can I do this?

Comment: `//div[@id='vulnerability']/text()` might work. What HTML parser are you using?

Comment: thank you @Blender .it works.I use html = urllib.urlopen(url).read() for parsing HTML page.I have another question, if I want to retrieve an attribute of a tag, for example I want to retrieve href attribute of this tag :<li><a href="http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/">Mozilla Firefox Homepage</a>  .what should I do?

Comment: It's basic XPath: `//a/@href`